# add animation button addtocart to top cart

Tags: product, cart

you can add, when you click on the button "add to cart" an animation that brings the button or the photo product to the top cart.

You must try to directly hand or there is something to be activated, even modules?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really clear, but if I understand correctly you want to animate the productimage to 'glide' to the cart in the top header whenever the Add To Cart button is clicked?

You can do this fairly simple with jQuery, something like this:

```
jQuery('.addtocart').click(function(){ 
    jQuery('.productimage').animate({
        width: 10%,
        right: "100",
        top: "100",
        height: auto
    });
});
```

This is untested, but it might be what you need. This would 'launch' the productimage to the top right corner of the site, and shrink it down to 10% of the width. Effectively shrinking the product image toward the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but I think you need ajax add to cart extension so once you click on add to cart it will show the loader and it will update the product in the top cart with the popup.

Here are some extension you can use

For Magento 1
https://github.com/manishiitg/excellence_magento_blog/tree/master/Ajax%20Add%20Cart%20Module

For Magento 2
https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/
https://amasty.com/ajax-shopping-cart-for-magento-2.html

Please mark the answer if this solution works for you.